# Reading the csv and formatting it to a dictionary with Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, format

I ma trying to convert the Code below to `pandas`. How would I be able to do convert to have both `reader` functions equivalent so that `account_strats` function works. The `pandas` implementation is faulty giving error defined below, how would I be able to fix it and convert it into `pandas` type.

CSV:

```
Name,AccountName,Type
XXX,Account1,RSIStrategy
XYB,Account1,MACDStrategy2.0
XBR,Account1,STDandRegressionStrategy
```

Code that works:

```
import csv 

for account in range(2):
    file = open("SavedStrats.csv")
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    account_strats = [strat for strat in reader if strat["AccountName"] == account]
    file.close()
```

Pandas Implementation(Code faulty):

```
import pandas as pd

for account in range(2):
    reader= pd.read_csv("SavedStrats.csv").to_dict('dict')
    account_strats = [strat for strat in reader if strat["AccountName"] == account]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, what you need is to_dict('**records**')

```
import pandas as pd

for account in range(2):
    reader= pd.read_csv("SavedStrats.csv").to_dict('records')
    account_strats = [strat for strat in reader if strat["AccountName"] == account]
```